# How to have the least hassle beating a Butterfree?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

My son  is 7 and he is playing Pokemon Red Fire on-line. He was frustrated playing against a trainer's level 20 Butterfree. He ended up with most of his pokemon party paralyzed or asleep and with Pokemon Fire Red having a potion being a turn then you end up locked in the effect. I settled on Nidoran and it was only because the Butterfree failed a sleep effect that the battle ended. Without cheating, how can he best counter a Butterfree?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, Grass-type Pokémon are immune to powder and spore moves (such as Sleep Powder and Stun Spore) while Electric-type Pokémon are immune to paralysis only starting from Generation VI.

That should be too early to get Drowzee (with [Insomnia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Insomnia_(Ability)) ability) or Persian (with [Limber](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Limber_(Ability)) ability).

Your best bet is using a fast Pokemon with Fire/Electric/Rock attack, in order to exploit Butterfree's weaknesses to those types and kill it before getting those annoying status.

Another strategy is trying to get one of your Pokemon poisoned, in that way it won't be able to be paralyzed or fall asleep.

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that Butterfree has a x4 weakness to Rock while only having a x2 weakness to Fire and Electric (of course because of it’s booty base HP and Defense probably wouldn’t matter on which type they use)

Comment: Which are fast pokemon with fast fire/electric/.rock attacks?

Comment: Charmander as starter, Pikachu can be found in Viridian Forest, or you can teach [Rock Tomb](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rock_Tomb_(move)) to Mankey, which can be found on Route 3-4

Comment: The first paragraph is irrelevant. As you said, Grass-type being immune to powders etc only applies from Gen VI onwards, not Pokemon Fire Red

Comment: @MBorg it's the actual "state of art", I thought it was a good thing to inform OP that it's possible to counter those status moves on newer generations.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to counter status moves in Fire Red is probably by giving your Pokémon a Lum Berry to hold. This will automatically heal any status effects your Pokémon is inflicted with, though it is single use. Butterfree ultimately doesn't have very good stats, and it has weaknesses to Rock, Fire, Flying, Ice and Electric. Its defence is lower than its special defence, so the physical moves (Rock and Flying) are likely to be a little better; and in particular, it has a four times weakness to Rock, so any decently strong Rock move will hurt it a lot. Assuming he's beaten Brock, the first gym leader, he will have TM39, Rock Tomb, at the least. With a Lum Berry you should be guaranteed at least one attack even if it hits you with a Sleep Powder, as you will wake up instantly.

In general, levelling up your own Pokémon will nearly always help you for a tough battle, and making use of the type matchup chart (press L or R in battle and then select Type Matchup List) to find super effective moves will go a long way.

Comment: [Lum berries](https://www.serebii.net/itemdex/lumberry.shtml) can be found in Route 8, while level 20 Butterfree's [trainer](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kanto_Route_6#Generation_III_2) is in Route 6.